# Problem with segmentation_models with array dimension during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a binary image segmentation model using the segmentation_models library with Keras and Tensorflow in Google Colab, but I am getting the following error:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function 
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models/base/objects.py", line 114, in __call__ 
        return self.l1(gt, pr) + self.l2(gt, pr)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models/losses.py", line 130, in __call__ 
        return F.binary_crossentropy(gt, pr, **self.submodules)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models/base/functional.py", line 256, in binary_crossentropy 
        return backend.mean(backend.binary_crossentropy(gt, pr))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5707, in binary_crossentropy 
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((1, 512, 512, 1) vs (1, 512, 512, 3))
```

When opening the images for training, I use the following code

```
for directory_path in glob.glob("images_bone/"):
    index = 0 
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.png")):
        if index % 4 < 3:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            train_images.append(img)
        index += 1

train_images = np.array(train_images)
```

The array dimensions are `(376, 512, 512, 3)`. Changing `IMREAD_COLOR` to `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` and adding an extra dimension with a value of 1 to create dimensions of `(1, 512, 512, 1)` results in the following error while training the model:

```
    
    Input 0 of layer "bn_data" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis 3 of input shape to have value 3, but received input with shape (1, 512, 512, 1)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'model_5' (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 512, 512, 1), dtype=uint8)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

I also trained a model with 3 classes using the `(376, 512, 512, 3)` array dimensions without any problems, so I suggest, while the axis 3 value in image opening is showing grayscale or color, it expects the number of classes on axis 3 during training the model.

I appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.